# Load Excel to table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I want to load data from Excel to table using SQL query.

I found using openrowset, but it is throwing the error:

> Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
> for linked server "(null)".

```
SELECT * into temptable
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
                'Excel 8.0;Database=E:\Users\koushik.veldanda\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx;IMEX=1',
                'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, install the right driver and try again.

How can you tell what drivers are installed?  Open up the ODBC Data Source Administrator window (Start > Run > type ODBCAD32.EXE and enter) and have a look in the Drivers tab.  The following screenshot (taken on a Dutch Windows XP) shows both the JET 4.0 driver for Excel 97-2003 and the fairly-new ACE driver for Excel 2007.
[image]

The drivers can be downloaded from the following pages on the Microsoft site:

Excel 97-2003 Jet 4.0 driver

Excel 2007 ACE driver – 12.00.6423.1000

Excel 2010 ACE driver (beta) – 14.00.4732.1000

Sidenote: the Excel 2010 driver is not supported on Windows XP, but I was able to query the 2010 Excel sheet using the 2007 driver.  I guess that this is the result of the Office Open XML standard which was introduced in Office 2007.

check this link it may be helpful:

http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2010/03/29/retrieving-data-from-excel/

Comment: @OcasoProtal thanks for your comments. here after i will provide my answer suggested way.

Comment: I need to use this query in some sproc so I need query

Answer (score 0):

first you have to enabling `'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries'`

```
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

then you have to follow below link instruction to solve this error

> The OLE DB provider Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0 for linked server (null) some

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/The-OLE-DB-provider-Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0-for-linked-server-null.aspx

after successfully follow the above instruction then you have to restart the machine if you get this error

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
>   server

then you can run your query

```
SELECT * into newtable
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=D:\Personal\MyTest.xlsx',
    'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]');
```

then refresh the DB you see new table is created with data